# focus on content within the link

Tags: html, css

Below is some html code that i am trying to store collapsible div tags
I am having a problem that when i click on the link Overland Expo April27 2011 which is contained along with other links which expand within the adventure diaries div, that focus is going to the top of the page. I want when you click on one of the links that focus remains on the content within that collapsible link div. Dose anyone have some advice please

```
   <!--<div> <a href="#para2"><a href="#" onclick="return toggleMe('para1')"/><h3>Click for adventure diaries</h3></a><br/>

 <link="para2" style="display:none">< link="#" onclick="return toggleMe('para1')" /></a>  
 <div id="para1" style="display:none">  

<p class="myTab" id="test">Content
</p


 </div><!-- end of first date --> -->
```

Comment: I had to rename the href to "link" because I'm a new member and can only use 2 in my question.

Answer (score 0):

See your `onclick="return toggleMe('para1')"`

When the `onclick` function returns `false`, the link does nothing -- so it won't take the page to `#`.

You need to change `toggleMe` to return false.